# What does $ mean in an output?

Tags: warning-messages, output, symbols

Solving a function in more than one variable, Mathematica gives me output in this way:

> name_variable$number

instead of giving me a number. I looked for symbol:

> $

online, but unfortunately I can't find what it means.

--sorry for my English--

---

example - creating a function quadrilateral:

```
Q[q_, x1, y1_, l1_, l2_, l3_, l4_] :=
  Module[{x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, theta1, theta2},
    x2 =x1 + l1 Cos[q];
    y2 =y1 + l1 Sin[q];
    (*others*) 
    {x2, y2, y3, x3, theta1, theta2}
  ]

p = Q[q, 0, 0, 3, 5, 2, 4, ...]
```

It gives me a Out like: `{..., theta2**$**6657, ...}` where 6657 is a random number

Comment: Please show a complete _but minimal_ example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: `$` can mean dollars, as in the output from evaluating `Quantity[10, "Dollars"]`.

Comment: From the documentation for [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html): "Module creates a symbol with name xxx\$nnn to represent a local variable with name xxx. The number nnn is the current value of \$ModuleNumber. "

Answer (score 13):

This usually means you've exported a local symbol from the context in which it was localized. Consider:

```
Module[{x}, x]
(* x$24939 *)
```

Your results may vary. The `Module` *localizes* `x` to avoid conflicting with any previous definition. `x$24939` is just another symbol similar to `x`, but with `$24939` added to its name to insure that there's no confusion with any other `x`.

To yield the symbol without modification, remove it from the list of symbols localized by `Module`.

Comment: So, what may I do to resolve this conflict?

Comment: @pinpose23 For me, I usually have to fix the problem with my code.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working as intended, I would think:

```
Q[q_, x1_, y1_, l1_, l2_, l3_, l4_] :=
 Module[{x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, theta1, theta2},
   x2 = x1 + l1 Cos[q];
   y2 = y1 + l1 Sin[q];
   (*others*)
   {x2, y2, y3, x3, theta1, theta2}
 ]

Q[q, 0, 0, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

This returns:

```
{3 Cos[q], 3 Sin[q], y3$62555, x3$62555, theta1$62555, theta2$62555}
```

The calculated values of `x2` and `y2` are returned but, since you do not have definitions for y3, x3, theta1, theta2 in your `Module`, they are returned unevaluated in their localized form, as mentioned above.

To avoid this, you need to provide definitions for those values as well.

Notice also that your original code was missing a `_` after `x1` in the argument list of `Q`.